# 「保留」より「改善待ち」がよい

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語, 質問のクローズ

質問の[「クローズ」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)は、よくない質問を選り分けて回答の労力をセーブする機能であると同時に、よくない質問を改善するためのプロセスの一環でもあります:

1. 質問にクローズ票が5票集まると、最初の5日間は「保留」状態になる
2. 質問にはクローズの理由と、改善をうながすメッセージが表示される
3. 「保留」中に質問が編集されると、[「再オープン」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)レビューキューに入れられ、[再オープン権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)<sup>1</sup>のあるユーザーにレビューされる
4. 再オープン票が5票集まると、再オープンされる (再オープンは「保留」状態でも「クローズ済み」状態でも可能)

保留状態の質問の例:

[image: 保留]

このように「保留」状態が別に設けられているのは、「クローズ」がその質問の生命の終わりではないことを明示するためです。が、まだ押しが弱いように思います。「保留」にしたコミュニティー側のアクション待ちである、という印象を持つこともありえます (質問者以外が編集して再オープンのリクエストをする、という場合ももちろんありますが)。

例えば **「改善待ち」** という名前にした方が意図が伝わりやすいのではないかと思います。どうでしょうか。

<sub><sup>1</sup> 再オープン権限とクローズ権限は同時に開放される</sub>

Comment: いいですね。専門用語に足してくれますか？実は「保留」はコミュニティのアクションというより、投稿者のアクションを待っています。コミュニティがしてもいいですが、質問量が増えると増えるほど編集する責任は投稿者に残ります。日本語で主語がないため、これはちょうどいいと思います。

Comment: [専門用語](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/265/30)に足しました

Comment: 英語で似たような話がありました：http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70061/i-propose-changing-the-term-closed-out-for-something-else

Comment: @jmac ["on hold"機能を発表した投稿](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173497/157841)でも似た話がありました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

全体的に「保留」を「改善待ち」に変更済みだと思います（次回のビルドに適用）。ヘルプセンターはまだ適用していないが、サイト全体で「保留」を見掛けたら、ご教示ください。