# ヘルプセンターの記事に[保留]という表現が残っている

Tags: バグ, 完了, ヘルプ, 専門用語

質問にクローズ票が集まると、5日間は「クローズ済み」ではなく「改善待ち」と表示されます。これは以前「保留」と訳されていましたが、「改善待ち」に変更されました。（参考 [「保留」より「改善待ち」がよい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1562/8000)）

しかし、クローズに関するヘルプセンターの記事では未だに「保留」という表現が使われています。

[ヘルプ センター > 質問にあたって > 質問が [クローズ済み] または [保留] とは?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

単に用語の変更ですから、 `[保留]` を `[改善待ち]` に置換すればいいかと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

適用しました。ミスがあったら、ご教示ください：

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions